# Will a program compiled in Mono for Windows run in Mono for Linux out of the box?

Tags: c#, windows, linux, mono

Will a program compiled in Mono for Windows run in Linux (with Mono) out of the box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:

Maybe.

Longer answer:

If you are not using Windows specific namespaces (such as the WMI namespace) and windows specific concepts (like **not** having `\` embedded in file paths instead of using [`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx)), things should work just fine.

To check whether your application is expected to work, use the [Mono Migration Analyzer](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA).

Comment: "It depends". The classic answer to this kind of extremely broad question. =)